# Programmatically obtain the Android API level of a device?

Tags: android

How can I find out which API level my device is using?

The firmware version is 1.6.  Does that mean it uses API Level 4?

Answer (score 114):

You can obtain API level programatically by the system constant (`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`). For example you can run some piece of code which requires newer API in the following way (it will execute if the current device's API level is at least 4)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {

}
```

To obtain user visible Android Version use:

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 40):

What you need: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

```
SDK_INT value        Build.VERSION_CODES        Human Version Name       
    1                  BASE                      Android 1.0 (no codename)
    2                  BASE_1_1                  Android 1.1 Petit Four
    3                  CUPCAKE                   Android 1.5 Cupcake
    4                  DONUT                     Android 1.6 Donut
    5                  ECLAIR                    Android 2.0 Eclair
    6                  ECLAIR_0_1                Android 2.0.1 Eclair                  
    7                  ECLAIR_MR1                Android 2.1 Eclair
    8                  FROYO                     Android 2.2 Froyo
    9                  GINGERBREAD               Android 2.3 Gingerbread
   10                  GINGERBREAD_MR1           Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread
   11                  HONEYCOMB                 Android 3.0 Honeycomb
   12                  HONEYCOMB_MR1             Android 3.1 Honeycomb
   13                  HONEYCOMB_MR2             Android 3.2 Honeycomb
   14                  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH        Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich
   15                  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1    Android 4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich
   16                  JELLY_BEAN                Android 4.1 Jellybean
   17                  JELLY_BEAN_MR1            Android 4.2 Jellybean
   18                  JELLY_BEAN_MR2            Android 4.3 Jellybean
   19                  KITKAT                    Android 4.4 KitKat
   20                  KITKAT_WATCH              Android 4.4 KitKat Watch
   21                  LOLLIPOP                  Android 5.0 Lollipop
   22                  LOLLIPOP_MR1              Android 5.1 Lollipop
   23                  M                         Android 6.0 Marshmallow
   24                  N                         Android 7.0 Nougat
   25                  N_MR1                     Android 7.1.1 Nougat
   26                  O                         Android 8.0 Oreo
   27                  O_MR1                     Android 8.1 Oreo MR1
   28                  P                         Android 9 Pie
   29                  Q                         Android 10 Q
  10000                CUR_DEVELOPMENT           Current Development Version
```

Answer (score 12):

For **API Level >= 4** you can use **Build.VERSION.SDK_INT**

```
private String getAndroidVersion(int sdk) {
    switch (sdk) {
        case 1:  return                          "(Android 1.0)";
        case 2:  return  "Petit Four"          + "(Android 1.1)";
        case 3:  return  "Cupcake"             + "(Android 1.5)";
        case 4:  return  "Donut"               + "(Android 1.6)";
        case 5:  return  "Eclair"              + "(Android 2.0)";
        case 6:  return  "Eclair"              + "(Android 2.0.1)";
        case 7:  return  "Eclair"              + "(Android 2.1)";
        case 8:  return  "Froyo"               + "(Android 2.2)";
        case 9:  return  "Gingerbread"         + "(Android 2.3)";
        case 10: return  "Gingerbread"         + "(Android 2.3.3)";
        case 11: return  "Honeycomb"           + "(Android 3.0)";
        case 12: return  "Honeycomb"           + "(Android 3.1)";
        case 13: return  "Honeycomb"           + "(Android 3.2)";
        case 14: return  "Ice Cream Sandwich"  + "(Android 4.0)";
        case 15: return  "Ice Cream Sandwich"  + "(Android 4.0.3)";
        case 16: return  "Jelly Bean"          + "(Android 4.1)";
        case 17: return  "Jelly Bean"          + "(Android 4.2)";
        case 18: return  "Jelly Bean"          + "(Android 4.3)";
        case 19: return  "KitKat"              + "(Android 4.4)";
        case 20: return  "KitKat Watch"        + "(Android 4.4)";
        case 21: return  "Lollipop"            + "(Android 5.0)";
        case 22: return  "Lollipop"            + "(Android 5.1)";
        case 23: return  "Marshmallow"         + "(Android 6.0)";
        case 24: return  "Nougat"              + "(Android 7.0)";
        case 25: return  "Nougat"              + "(Android 7.1.1)";
        case 26: return  "Oreo"                + "(Android 8.0)";
        case 27: return  "Oreo"                + "(Android 8.1)";
        case 28: return  "Pie"                 + "(Android 9.0)";
        case 29: return  "Q"                   + "(Android 10.0)";
        case 30: return  "R"                   + "(Android 11.0)";
        default: return  "";
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
String android_os = getAndroidVersion(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

Comment: It's pointless, first you specify a Build limit but provide the case for previous api ... Build.VERSION.RELEASE will give you the numeric version, Build.Version.SDK_INT will give you a better analityc number. For the name, I guess you can use this reflection solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258693/4391450

Answer (score 5):

## Very easy:

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
String versionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

Log.e("MyActivity", "manufacturer " + manufacturer
            + " \n model " + model
            + " \n version " + version
            + " \n versionRelease " + versionRelease
     );
```

## Output:

```
E/MyActivity: manufacturer samsung 
                model SM-T310 
                version 19 
                versionRelease 4.4.2
```

Answer (score 4):

To get your device current API    :

```
int MyDeviceAPI = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get device's information, as following.

```
Log.d(TAG, "RELEASE : " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
Log.d(TAG, "SDK     : " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

and can get the Android version code history from OS.

```
for (Field field : Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  Log.d(TAG, field.get(this) + " -> " + field.getName());
}
```

This is output.

```
RELEASE : 5.1.1
SDK     : 22

1 -> BASE
2 -> BASE_1_1
3 -> CUPCAKE
10000 -> CUR_DEVELOPMENT
4 -> DONUT
5 -> ECLAIR
6 -> ECLAIR_0_1
7 -> ECLAIR_MR1
8 -> FROYO
9 -> GINGERBREAD
10 -> GINGERBREAD_MR1
11 -> HONEYCOMB
12 -> HONEYCOMB_MR1
13 -> HONEYCOMB_MR2
14 -> ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
15 -> ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
16 -> JELLY_BEAN
17 -> JELLY_BEAN_MR1
18 -> JELLY_BEAN_MR2
19 -> KITKAT
20 -> KITKAT_WATCH
21 -> L
21 -> LOLLIPOP
22 -> LOLLIPOP_MR1
```

so, combine these and [official version list](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html).

```
API VERSION_CODE           VERSION       CODE_NAME 
1   BASE                   1             (no code name)
2   BASE_1_1               1.1           (no code name)
3   CUPCAKE                1.5           Cupcake
4   DONUT                  1.6           Donut
5   ECLAIR                 2             Eclair
6   ECLAIR_0_1             2.0.1         Eclair
7   ECLAIR_MR1             2.1           Eclair
8   FROYO                  2.2.x         Froyo
9   GINGERBREAD            2.3 - 2.3.2   Gingerbread
10  GINGERBREAD_MR1        2.3.3 - 2.3.7 Gingerbread
11  HONEYCOMB              3             Honeycomb
12  HONEYCOMB_MR1          3.1           Honeycomb
13  HONEYCOMB_MR2          3.2.x         Honeycomb
14  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH     4.0.1 - 4.0.2 Ice Cream Sandwich
15  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1 4.0.3 - 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich
16  JELLY_BEAN             4.1.x         Jelly Bean
17  JELLY_BEAN_MR1         4.2.x         Jelly Bean
18  JELLY_BEAN_MR2         4.3.x         Jelly Bean
19  KITKAT                 4.4 - 4.4.4   KitKat
20  KITKAT_WATCH           4.4W          KitKat Watch
21  LOLLIPOP               5             Lollipop
22  LOLLIPOP_MR1           5.1           Lollipop
23  M                      6             Marshmallow
24  N                      7             Nougat
25  N_MR1                  7.1           Nougat
```

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#N_MR1) says, a version_code of API25 is N_MR1.

Answer (score 3):

in first versions was used `Build.VERSION.SDK`

```
 String myAPI= Build.VERSION.SDK;
```

**but now is deprecated!.**

> **[SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK)**  This field was deprecated in API level 4. Use SDK_INT to easily
>   get this as an integer.

#### now you have to use: **SDK_INT** Added in API level 4 :

```
  int myAPI = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

> **[SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)**  The user-visible SDK version of the framework; its possible
>   values are defined in Build.VERSION_CODES.

more info:

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html**