# Why doesn't the android SDK warn me about backward compatibility issues?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-tools

I set my minimum API version to 8, but the android SDK fails to warn me when I use functions that were added in API 14. Why is that?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Android tools -> Run Lint.
The Lint tool will warn you. It also checks for incompleteness in your strings file etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's your minimum **supported** level, not minimum **required**. It's reasonable to want to support up to the latest API (or API 14 for example) and gracefully degrade certain features all the way down to API 8. You can include functionality from API levels higher than your minimum, and [simply check the version code at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993924/android-api-level), and go down different code paths as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you project target,

**Right click on project--> property --> android --> API 8 --> apply --> ok**

Then clean and refresh the project, your problem will be solve..:)