# Reading storage wont work with Android tablet

Tags: android

So I can read data directly using path '/storage/sdcard0' with my Sony Xperia but if I try same thing with my Prestigio tablet it does not work. However if I tried to read from '/storage/sdcard0/Music' with tablet it works perfectly and lists all files like it should. 
I enabled reading/writing from external storage but problem is still here, tablet can read files that are under 'sdcard0' but can't read from 'sdcard0' directly, with Xperia however it doesn't matter.

So if anyone know how to solve this problem I would be thankful.

Comment: what is the api level of your Sony Xperia and Prestigio IPad

Comment: What is an Android iPad?

Comment: @Drunk Bearzz : Seriously!! what is an Android iPad ??

Comment: @AbhayBohra  when I use 'android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT' it gives value of 17 so it should be 'Android 4.2 Jellybean' for Prestigio, for Xperia it's 'Android 5.0 Lollipop' according to list from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993924/get-android-api-level-of-phone-currently-running-my-application

Comment: Also in my country IPad and tablet are the same thing and it doesn't metter who manufacturer is but I'll edit it so it's less confusing.