# Is there a good way to API check on Android App?

Tags: android

Is there a good way to test if some API is compatible for older versions or not deprecated on newer versions than target platform, without running on the device or emulator on which the OS is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/01/how-to-use-gyroscope-api-and-remain.html) may help you. It shows how to gracefully remain compatible with low API levels while using features introduced in more recent API levels.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation. Also set your API level appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Check out  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768806/how-to-obtain-the-android-api-level-of-a-device)  to find the Build version of the device and use suitable if clauses 
before using newer APIs.