# Unfortunately App has Stopped - showing Toast in if-else condition

Tags: android

**I just simply want to show Toast if device supports SDK <= 13 that's it**

I am writing a small program in which allowing user to add an event to user if target sdk greater than or equal to 14 else showing Toast, but getting Unfortunately App has Stopped whenever i am using my code on device which supports API Level 8 or < 14 in place of Toast, see below code:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
                 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13)
                 {   
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                             
                }                
                 else 
                 {
                     Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                     calIntent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
                     calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title.toString());
                     calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, KEY_LOCATION);
                     calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description.toString());
                     startActivity(calIntent);   
                }
             }
         });
    }
```

*Logcat:*

```
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.provider.CalendarContract$Events
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.example.multileveljson.ProductDetailActivity$1.onClick(ProductDetailActivity.java:51)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-30 12:24:27.142: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am able to add events to devices those are using target sdk >= 14 but not able to show Toast on Devices those are using target SDK <= 13....

Comment: what is error in logcat ??

Comment: Do you want your Toast to show on API Level 13 ? It seems yes from your question. Then you should modify your condition <= 13

Comment: Its working perfectly fine for me.Please check this "<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />" in manifest file.

Comment: @MukeshKumar see my log report

Comment: @AbrahimNeil what is line 51 `ProductDetailActivity.java`?

Comment: Your logcat suggests that the issue is not with this code you've posted. Its with the CalendarContracts.Events class.

Comment: @Raghunandan LINE number 51 : calIntent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);

Comment: thanks to all of you, each and every one :) finally problem resolved, what code need to write to add an event to device which supports api level <= 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace `ProductDetailActivity.this` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Also, Calendar Contacts introduced in 4.0 which is 14+ sdk.

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 13
```

Before 4.0 they had `android.provider.Calendar`

You may want to investigate that.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question. this one should be closed. or we answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The class `CalendarContract.Events` which is you are using is added in API level 14 so thats why it is giving you exception if you want to use it your ApI version must be 14..so before Api 14 the calss is not found in the Android SDK..

Comment: No..once its not because of the toast..Logcat is clearly showing NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I just simply want to show if device supports SDK <= 13 that's it

Comment: you can not..check this for more info..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601456/how-to-use-calendarcontract-class-in-api-level-8

Comment: see this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401237/how-to-add-an-event-to-native-calendar