# Recognizer Intent not able to define its constants

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am using the activity, [voicerecognition.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html), provided by Google to allow the user to choose a language, talk into the handset, and view what they have just said. It works when I take out all the language constants, but when I put the language options in, I get errors.
For example:

- The method getVoiceDetailsIntent(VoiceRecognition) is undefined for the type
- EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES cannot be resolved or is not a field
- EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE cannot be resolved or is not a field
- The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method

I thought I might just need to update the SDK or something but everything is up to date. I have no idea what is wrong since I copied the activity exactly as is on the link provided.

```
package com.sample.voicerecog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VoiceRecognition extends Activity implements OnClickListener {    
private static final String TAG = "VoiceRecognition";    
private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;    
private ListView mList;    
private Handler mHandler;    
private Spinner mSupportedLanguageView;    

/**     
 * Called with the activity is first created.     
 */    
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    mHandler = new Handler();        

    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.        
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);        

    // Get display items for later interaction        
    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);        
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);        
    mSupportedLanguageView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.supported_languages);        
    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present        
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();        
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(                
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);        
    if (activities.size() != 0) {            
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);        
    } else {           
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);      
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");   
    }      

    // Most of the applications do not have to handle the voice settings. If the application     
    // does not require a recognition in a specific language (i.e., different from the system     
    // locale), the application does not need to read the voice settings.      
    refreshVoiceSettings();  
}

/**
 * Handle the click on the start recognition button.     
 */    
public void onClick(View v) {        
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {           
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();        
    }    
}   

/**     
 * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.     
 */    
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {       
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        

    // Display an hint to the user about what he should say.      
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");    

    // Given an hint to the recognizer about what the user is going to say       
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,              
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);    

    // Specify how many results you want to receive. The results will be sorted   
    // where the first result is the one with higher confidence.       
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5); 

    // Specify the recognition language. This parameter has to be specified only if the     
    // recognition has to be done in a specific language and not the default one (i.e., the   
    // system locale). Most of the applications do not have to set this parameter.  
    if (!mSupportedLanguageView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Default")) {     
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,                  
                mSupportedLanguageView.getSelectedItem().toString());  
    }    
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);   
}    

/**     
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.     
 */    
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {           
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard           
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(                 
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);          
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,      
                matches));       
    } 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);   
}

private void refreshVoiceSettings() {      
    Log.i(TAG, "Sending broadcast");    
    sendOrderedBroadcast(RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(this), null,   
            new SupportedLanguageBroadcastReceiver(), null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);   
} 

private void updateSupportedLanguages(List<String> languages) {    
    // We add "Default" at the beginning of the list to simulate default language.   
    languages.add(0, "Default");   

    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,    
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages.toArray(    
                    new String[languages.size()])); 
    mSupportedLanguageView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

private void updateLanguagePreference(String language) {      
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.language_preference);     
    textView.setText(language); 
}  

/**     
 * Handles the response of the broadcast request about the recognizer supported languages.     
 *     
 * The receiver is required only if the application wants to do recognition in a specific language.     
 */  

private class SupportedLanguageBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {      
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {     
        Log.i(TAG, "Receiving broadcast " + intent);  
        final Bundle extra = getResultExtras(false); 
        if (getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {    
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {     
                @Override        
                public void run() {              
                    showToast("Error code:" + getResultCode());    
                }       
            });   
        }
        if (extra == null) {        
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {          
                @Override             
                public void run() {  
                    showToast("No extra");       
                }
            });
        }      
        if (extra.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {         
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {      
                @Override       
                public void run() {          
                    updateSupportedLanguages(extra.getStringArrayList(      
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES));     
                }
            });
        }      
        if (extra.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE)) {    
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {         
                @Override      
                public void run() {          
                    updateLanguagePreference(     
                            extra.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE));       
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {      
        Toast.makeText(VoiceRecognition.this, text, 1000).show();   
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What api level are you on? Did you try Android Tools -> Fix project properties? The features you have mentioned are only available from API level 8. Make sure your project is at this API level.

Comment: I'm using level 4 and yes, I did try to fix project properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your project is at a lower API level than level 8. To fix this, if you are using Eclipse, right click on your project and click properties. Choose Android from the menu on the left, and select a different project build target. If you don't find one at level 8 or higher, click on Window -> Android SDK Manager and install one. You can see what features of RecognizerIntent are available at the various API levels [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html).

Comment: Thanks! However, all run() are still showing errors. Eclipse suggests that I delete the override. Should I do that or is there another solution? Also, is there a way to use API level 8 when the handset is level 8 or greater and have language options available or use lower than API level 8 when the handset is less than 8 and not provide language selection? (Sorry for the run on sentence)

Comment: see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-qt/browse_thread/thread/fc9c3830e3582db8) link for the compiler errors on the override annotation. Yes, you can use the Build.VERSION class to determine the level at runtime and take change your UI accordingly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768806/how-to-obtain-the-android-api-level-of-a-device) link for more information.

Comment: I'm using JRE 1.7. The solution was going from 1.5 to 1.6. I tried going to 1.6 but that didn't work. Went back to 1.7 and it still doesn't work.