# How to use a function only if the version is 11+

Tags: android, version, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

in my code i'm using the a function with "query text change"
but it's only supported from android 11
this is a simple search bar.
how to verify the current version of android, and show a different activity?
thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are many questions about that. Check [Get Android API level of phone currently running my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993924/get-android-api-level-of-phone-currently-running-my-application) and [Programmatically obtain the Android API level of a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768806/programmatically-obtain-the-android-api-level-of-a-device) . In these answers,
you might see something like:

```
Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
```

But `.SDK` has been deprecated. Use `SDK_INT` instead

```
//Check the condition as
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11){}
```

See [Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) for more.

**Update**:

As [kcoppock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321697/kcoppock) has nicely suggested, you may want to use something like:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: To be more verbose, you can use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB`

Answer (score 3):

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` will tell you the SDK number.